# Fortran MPI - Ping pong program segfaults

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, mpi

I'm trying to learn some MPI stuff in Fortran, but I'm having some issues. This ping pong program segfaults between the two comments that say SEGFAULT HERE, but for the life of me, I cannot understand why that is.

```
program MPI_PING_PONG
    implicit none
    include 'mpif.h'
    integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    integer ping_pong_counter ! This will increment each time a message is received.
    integer isEven
    integer partner_rank
    call MPI_INIT(ierror)                            ! Initialize MPI on all processes.
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror) ! Tell each process the size of the world.
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror) ! Tell each process its rank.

    ping_pong_counter = 0
    partner_rank = mod(rank + 1,2)
    print *,'Process has rank ',rank
    do
        if (ping_pong_counter == 50) then
            exit
        endif
        isEven = mod(ping_pong_counter,2)
        if (rank == isEven) then
            ping_pong_counter = ping_pong_counter + 1
            print *,'Process ',rank,'sending counter value of ',ping_pong_counter
            call MPI_SEND(ping_pong_counter,1,MPI_INTEGER,partner_rank,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)
        else
!******************** SEGFAULT HERE ********************!
            call MPI_RECV(ping_pong_counter,1,MPI_INTEGER,partner_rank,5,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)
!******************** SEGFAULT HERE ********************!
            print *,'Process ',rank,' has received a counter with value ',ping_pong_counter
        endif
    enddo
end program MPI_PING_PONG
```

This is the output below:

```
Process has rank 0
Process 0 sending counter value of 1
Process has rank 1

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation Fault - invalid memory reference

Backtrace for this error:
#0: 0x7F49425F2117
#1: 0x7F49425F26F4
#2: 0x7F49425F20AF
#3: 0x7F49425F22C7
#4: 0X400DDF in mpi_ping_pong at MPI_PING_PONG.f90:28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `status` argument. The correct signature of `MPI_Recv` is

```
 MPI_RECV(BUF, COUNT, DATATYPE, SOURCE, TAG, COMM, STATUS, IERROR)   
 <type>    BUF(*)
     INTEGER    COUNT, DATATYPE, SOURCE, TAG, COMM
     INTEGER    STATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), IERROR
```

You have wrong number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The presence in the backtrace of addresses that normally belong to the stack space hints at missing non-optional subroutine or function arguments.

One should not use the `mpif.h` interface in modern Fortran programs but rather the `mpi` module interface (`USE mpi`). With MPI-3.0 implementations one should use the the `mpi_f08` interface. The `mpi` module interface provides argument checking for many functions and passing the wrong number of arguments will be caught as early as during the compilation of the program. Unfortunately `MPI_RECV` is a function that takes an argument of varying type (the buffer) and is therefore often omitted from the `mpi` module interface since Fortran before version 2008 does not allow interfaces with varying-type arguments to be declared. Some MPI implementations work around this limitation by using long lists of possible types for the buffer argument. The same applies to other communication calls too, e.g. to `MPI_SEND`.

In an ideal world we would all have MPI-3.0 compatible implementations and Fortran 2008 compilers that implement TR 29113. The `mpi_f08` module interface takes advantage of the ability to declare subroutine interfaces with arguments of varying type and shape and the compiler is able to easily check all arguments at compile time.